# Replace XML values in one XML from another document XML array of nodes values with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have troubles with a replacement values in a XML documents.

I have these two pieces of xml:

XmlFile_1

```
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B3-8" Name="     ">../Metadata/A_short_autobiography_of_Herculino_Alves.imdi</CorpusLink>
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B5-E" Name=" tttttt    ">../Metadata/Wordlist_and_phrases_-_modifiers.imdi</CorpusLink>

<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B9-6" Name=" hhhhhh    ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/The_Turtle_and_the_Deer.imdi</CorpusLink>
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72BB-1" Name=" jjjjjj    ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/Wordlist_and_phrases_parts_of_a_tree.imdi</CorpusLink>
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72BD-B" Name=" kkkkk    ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/Wordlist_and_phrases_.imdi</CorpusLink>
```

XMLFile2

```
<Session>
  <Name>des2008_002_ab</Name>
```

I need to replace the value of  each "CorpusLink.Name" in Xmlfile_1 for the value on Session.Name in XmlFile_2;XmlFile_3;XmlFile_4;XmlFile_5;XmlFile_5 once that I have several xml documents like XmlFile_2.

Basically, the idea is to replace the values like this

```
xmldoc1.Corpuslink.Name = xmldoc2.Session.Name
xmldoc1.Corpuslink.Name = xmldoc3.Session.Name                  
xmldoc1.Corpuslink.Name = xmldoc4.Session.Name
xmldoc1.Corpuslink.Name = xmldoc5.Session.Name                       
...
```

For now I have this code:

```
$Targfiles = Get-ChildItem C:\WorkingFolder\ *.xml
$TrgContent = [xml](Get-Content $Targfiles)

$Sourcfiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$Sourcfiles = Get-ChildItem C:\WorkingFolder\Source\*.xml
$SrcContent = Foreach ($item in $Sourcfiles){[xml] (Get-Content $item)}

$TrgContent.METATRANSCRIPT.Corpus.CorpusLink | ForEach-Object {[String]$_.Name= Foreach ($element in $SrcContent)    {$element.METATRANSCRIPT.Corpus.CorpusLink}}

$OutputFile=$Targfiles.Name
$TrgContent.Save("C:\WorkingFolder\output\$OutputFile")
```

The code is working but I can't get the result that i need , this is my problem:

```
$TrgContent.METATRANSCRIPT.Corpus.CorpusLink | ForEach-Object {[String]$_.Name= Foreach ($element in $SrcContent){$element.METATRANSCRIPT.Corpus.CorpusLink}}
```

RESULT:

```
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B3-8" Name="     ">../Metadata/A_short_autobiography_of_Herculino_Alves.imdi</CorpusLink>
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B5-E" Name="     ">../Metadata/Wordlist_and_phrases_-_modifiers.imdi</CorpusLink>
<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B7-9" Name="     ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/Wordlist_fruits_and_cultural_items.imdi</CorpusLink>

<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72B9-6" Name="     ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/The_Turtle_and_the_Deer.imdi</CorpusLink>

<CorpusLink ArchiveHandle="hdl:2196/00-0000-0000-000F-72BD-B" Name="     ">../desano-silva-0151/Metadata/Wordlist_and_phrases_.imdi</CorpusLink>
```

The values in CorpusLink.Name are empty. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value from the same tag an the `string` typecasting would also not require. Try below.

```
$i = 0
$TrgContent.METATRANSCRIPT.Corpus.CorpusLink | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name= $SrcContent[$i].Session.Name.'#text'
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This Working fine.